# Upload file using google cloud end points to google app engine application

Tags: javascript, php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have an application on Google App Engine written in python, i am using this application as a server to my web application written in PHP which i am using as client to call my server side api on GAE using javascript end point.

I want to upload file from my web application to my GAE application using google cloud end points.I studied about blob store but it didn't help much.

Please suggest what should i do.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the Cloud Storage to store your files, instead of Blobstore.

Use GCS because:

- Google is moving away from the blobstore
- GCS offers more functionality like acl, folders, and more.
- You can use filenames and a blobstore like serving url for images
- You can create serving url's for non images
- GCS is cheap and has a free default bucket

To using GCS, you have to use the https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/

Here is an exemple in Java to use this API:

```
GcsService gcsService = GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService();
GcsFilename filename = new GcsFilename(CONSTANTES.BUCKETNAME, unique+".jpg");
GcsFileOptions options = new GcsFileOptions.Builder()
                    .mimeType("image/jpg")
                    .acl("public-read")
                    .build();
GcsOutputChannel writeChannel = gcsService.createOrReplace(filename, options);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, i will try and implement it and let you know if it solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This is written (my mistake) as if you were on java. Feel free to use the analogous pattern for PHP on App Engine.

What the other user wrote about GCS answers the storage portion of your question - you should definitely use GCS - but as far as your idea of POSTing the form data to an endpoints function, this is definitely not advised. API calls should be little tiny pieces of data. An API should be like a paper airplane, lightly flying to your server to request some real data.

The way to have users upload files to GCS is to serve them a page with a file upload form (`enctype="multipart/form-data"`) where the form `action` parameter is an upload URL generated to template the page in your servlet's `doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)` method using the [GCS client library function `createUploadUrl()`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/blobstore/BlobstoreService#createUploadUrl%28java.lang.String%29). You can use it like this:

```
String uploadUrl = blobstoreService
                       .createUploadUrl("/upload", 
                                        UploadOptions.Builder.withGoogleStorageBucketName("my_bucket"));
```

In this manner you can obtain an upload URL for GCS that the user's file POST will go to. The route `/upload` is a route on your app that will be redirected once the upload is received. Any extra form parameters you add will still be visible to the request handler (a `doPost()` method on a servlet) which you define for that route.

With all of this info, you're ready to begin serving file upload forms to your users, without worrying about how this interacts with Cloud Endpoints. Use Endpoints to define API calls needed by your javascript/Android/iOS client, not for handling file uploads.